# Creating local environment with sts, maven, mysql and tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

HI - I want my local environment in chronology so everything works. Is there any or my approach should work?

I have jdk version 1.6 and my path and java_home are set in environment var

I have STS version 2.3.2, shall I upgrade and how?

I need maven to build my projects. Where and how to install it?

I need a server Tomcat? Anything else which is better to go with it?

I need preferable MySQL, how to install?

What is the chronology of these installs I need to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For maven install see:
  http://maven.apache.org/download.html#Installation_Instructions
- For tomcat install see:
  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html
- For grails install see:
  http://www.grails.org/Installation
- For mysql install see:
  http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Install chronology doesn't matter.